# Using Xpath selectors to extract / combine data from Javascript Objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I'm quite fond of [CakePHP Set class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1487/Set), it comes with a few awesome tools i now love. I use it mainly to [extract](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1501/extract) or [combine](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1492/combine) arrays.

I was wondering if there was a way to do just that with javascripts Objects/Arrays of data.

```
// Desired Usage:
var users = {User: {0:{id:1,name:'A'},1:{id:2,name:'B'}}}
var results = $.extract('/User/id', users);
// results returns:
// {0:1,1:2};

// /User[id>2][<5]  Selects all Users with an id > 2 but < 5
```

It could support on jQuery or maybe just Sizzle.

Do i have to develop thoses functions from zero or is there already some native/plugin xpath selector/extractor support out there ? Can Sizzle do this ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for that library http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/
Not sure, whether it could process request exactly in this syntax: User[id>2]**[<5]**,
but it's rather powerful library and should have similar feature.

Even if there's no function for request parts like "[<5]", you may call

```
.slice(0, 5);
```

Comment: Nice link, i've found this dojo function while googling json xpath http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/json/query#usage. Might be stronger but did not find source code to extract this one function.

Comment: Here's source for downloading this: http://dojotoolkit.org/download#getdojo. json.query is part of dojoX, not the dojo itself. The first ont is like Mootools More or jQuery plugins.